# GWT issues when using IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8, http-status-codes

I am making a remote procedural call from the client side and the core logic includes the execution of a query on the server side. This works perfectly for every browser except IE8. I get a status Code Exception with a code of 12152. When I googled this I found that it might have to do something with the session but there is no proper answer out there at this time. How do I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

yay for obsecur status codes. after some looking all things point to

> HTTP Status 12152 The server has been taken down momentarily for database or server maintenance, or there has been a network error. This status will generally come up when attempting to upload. Please try again later.

I would try increasing your time out on the server and client side. If that does work try routing though a different proxy, which sometimes those can mangle the headers in your request. If running though a proxy or anouymous web proxy does work, install fiddler2 or wireshark and inspect your request, mainly the headers. there might be something funky in there. You should also try sniffing on the server side and see how the incoming request looks too.

On your client side sniff on your open sockets to make sure you dont have a mess of open ports and such to the server. IE could complain about this too.

Unfortunetly its one of those errors that doesn't seem to direct.

You could also try using a different type or request with requestbuilder like using all get or post or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the response. I could finally figure out what the issue was luckily without even having to use tools like Fiddler.

In my case, for IE8, the logic in the RPC was getting executed the way it had to but then the connection was not being shut down. So I had to use an instance of RpcRequestBuilder with a RequestBuilder object that can accept header information and timeout information. In the header I put in "Connection : close" in order to make sure the connection shuts down once the RPC is through. Setting the timeout information allows me to get a RequestTimeoutException object as the Throwable object and based on that I can know if the RPC failed due to a timeout or some other bad logic.

Comment: you can do that too in RPC services but you have to overload the underlaying requestbuilder which can get messy if your not picky about how you create your base service class that you extend from.